Horizontal Scroll Animation Using GSAP
I am using GSAP to apply some scroll animation into my website. I have applied the vertical scrolling with section pin by setting a CSS class "section" to those that I want to vertically scroll. I want to do the same with horizontal scrolling, but it won't work. My code for vertical scrolling:
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)
gsap.utils.toArray(".section").forEach((panel, i) => {
    ScrollTrigger.create({
        trigger: panel,
        start: "top top",
        pin: true,
        pinSpacing: false,
        snap: {
            snapTo: 4 / (gsap.utils.toArray(".section").length - 1),
            duration: { min: 0.1, max: 0.2 },
            ease: "power1.inOut"
        }
    });
});

I have tried many ways like:
gsap.utils.toArray(".section").forEach((panel, i) => {
    ScrollTrigger.create({
        trigger: panel,
        start: "left left",
        pin: true,
        pinSpacing: false,
        scrub: true,
    });
});

gsap.to(".h-scroll", {
    xPercent: -100 * (gsap.utils.toArray(".section").length - 1),
    ease: "none", 
    scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".outer",
        pin: true,
        scrub: true,
    }
});

with the HTML structure:
<div class="outer">
<div class="h-scroll">
<div class="section"> <img /> </div>
<div class="section"> <h2>/*whatever*/</h2> </div>
</div>
</div>

But sections are just sliding next to each other. My goal is to get the next section over the previous one when scrolling down. Anyone has an idea of how to do it?
NOTE: I do not know if it is important to mention the framework, but in case it is, I am using wordpress.
